# Payments Callback URL not being call after new local currency changes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

After switching to the new Facebook local currency API the process is working, but 
my server is not involve in the process so i really don't know if the user bought coins cause the payment callback URL is not being called now (using static payment).

I tried to use real time update to get Facebook data but can make it work, what is the best practice to involve the server in the process so it will be aware of the purchase?

I prefer for security reasons to get the update from Facebook and not from my client.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after searching a log i found the solution

There are two primary methods through which you are notified of the outcome of the purchase, and a further method by which you can verify any payment information.

Firstly, Facebook will return details of the order via a JavaScript callback. The data sent to this callback includes:

payment_id, which uniquely identifies the transaction.
quantity, which indicates the amount of the item which was sold.
request_id, optionally, the developer can provide their own unique identification for the transaction when calling our Javascript SDK to render the payment dialog. This value is then returned upon purchase completion.
status, which indicates the current state of the transaction, i.e. 'pending', 'completed', 'failed' etc.

Secondly, Facebook will issue a realtime update notifying the developer that a new order has completed. The developer can subscribe to the payment_object callback to track order completions, using the payment_id as the unique identity parameter for each transaction.

Thirdly, at any time, the payment_id can be used to verify details of a transaction via the Graph API. Details such as the associated user_id, updated_time and amount can be queried, using the payment_id. The Graph API will also allow you to access further details including any refunds or disputes associated with the transaction.

If for some reason both the JavaScript callback and the realtime update fail and you do not receive the payment_id, we also allow you to query the Graph API using the optional request_id parameter, which can be specified by the developer when invoking the Facebook payment dialog.

please refer to:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/payments/
and to:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/fulfillment/#rtu